# Create a VSTO shape from byte array

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an image that is encoded in a byte array and I would like to add it as a shape in an excel document but unfortunetly the only available function I see to do this requires me to save the image to the drive and then read it. As you see this is a really slow operation and I would like to simply read the image from the byte stream and decode it into a bitmap.

I have encoded it like this :

```
                    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
                    encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
                    byte[] bit = null;
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
                        encoder.Save(ms);
                        bit = ms.ToArray();
                    }
```

Now, how to add it to the worksheet ? 
The method [Shapes.AddPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture.aspx) accepts only a filename and cannot read from a stream.

Comment: You have to save it on disk then load it from there, no other option is available.

Comment: If you don't want to save it on disk, then you can use clipboard object to paste image in Excel

Comment: That's a good idea but how can I get a handle of the image I inserted? @Sarvesh

Comment: You have to uniquely name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel object model doesn't provide any method for reading a byte array and then add it as a shape. So, the only possible solution is to save the byte array as a file on the disk and then add it as a shape as you stated earlier:

> to save the image to the drive and then read it.

Comment: That is just horrible. Absolutely horrible.